# How to change Mozilla Firefox quit shortcut?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu(version - 39.0)
I want to change the quit short-cut which is currently <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q.</kbd>. To some other keys, because sometime while closing tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W.</kbd>, I accidentally close my firefox.

How can I change it in my system? 
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I might be missing something, but I just tested every combination of [browser.tabs.warnOnClose](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About%3Aconfig_entries), [browser.warnOnQuit](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.warnOnQuit) and [browser.showQuitWarning](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/824072), and still no dialog showed up when closing a window with multiple tabs, either by clicking the close button or by hitting `Ctrl`+`Q`. I'm using Firefox 60.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. So I guess there's not much one can do apart from using extensions...

Comment: You could also disable `Ctrl+Q` system-wide: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1919/how-can-i-disable-ctrlq-for-all-applications-system-wide

Comment: As of Firefox 87 (March 2021), you can finally disable the `Ctrl+Q` shortcut, by going to `about:config` and setting `browser.quitShortcut.disabled` to `true`. Note that this will only apply after restarting the broswer. Thanks to @evilpie who contributed that solution to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1352295/112593)!

Comment: Ah, but that does not disable Ctrl+Shift+Q. Q being right next to TAB :'(

Comment: For me (Firefox 113) `browser.quitShortcut.disabled` worked, but only took effect after restarting Firefox. There is also `browser.warnOnQuitShortcut`, which seems to take effect immediately.

Comment: browser.warnOnQuitShortcut should default to True.  Thanks for that, @EM0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firefox offers no built-in editor for key bindings.

A solution exists to disable the shortcut starting with version Firefox 87, as given in the comments above by *waldyrious*. Thanks to Firefox developer Tom Schuster (user *evilpie*) and the patch to the 20 year-old [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52821) we have the updated [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1352295/458747) on superuser, reproduced here:

In `about:config` set the preference

```
browser.quitShortcut.disabled true
```

and restart the browser for it to take effect.

Comment: `keybinder` appears to be a successor to the discontinued Customizable Shortcuts: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/keybinder/

Comment: Keybinder works for me as well.

Comment: Check that: Keybinder will stop working permanently as of Firefox 57 per a note posted to the front page of [the official repository](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/keybinder).

Comment: Do you know of a solution for FF >= 57?

Comment: Any solutions nor 2018?  Customizable Shortcuts is disappeared.

Comment: The described solution works in FF 92. After setting the option you can use ctrl+q to stop the browser and once it starts again it should be fine :)

Answer (score 5):

To disable the shortcut without installing extensions:

1. Type `about:config` in the address bar
2. Type `browser.showQuitWarning` in the search field
3. Change the value to `true`

Comment: It does not work when you use the feature "Show my windows and tabs from last time" - [source bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691297)

Comment: This solution is the only one that actually works for the latest Firefox Quantum (suggested extensions are not compatible or are discontinued)

Answer (score 4):

Firefox does not allow changing shortcut keys out of the box (not even in `About:config`).

As far as I know, you have two options:

- For only disabling <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, you can use the very simple [Disable ctrl-q extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/disable-ctrl-q-shortcut/).
- For customizing other shortcuts, including ctrl+q, you can install [Menu Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/). To use it, access `Tools->Menu Wizard` and click the keyboard icon on the top right (in LTR layout) to display the list of shortcuts and select a new one.

Note: the `Customizable Shortcuts` extension mentioned in the previous answer was  discontinued and removed by its author (although the [source code](https://github.com/ttaubert/customizable-shortcuts) can still be found on github). Edit 2016-08-02: the add-on [keybinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/keybinder/) seems to be a successor to Customizable Shortcuts, although I haven't tried it personally.

Comment: I tried `Ctrl+Q` and `Alt+F4` for File->Exit in Menu Wizard. But FF ignores these shortcuts and does not quit. I tried [`Key Binder`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keybinder/?src=search), but this add-on does not show `Quit` or `Exit` in its shorcut list.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by this statement - those shortcuts are Firefox's default, and this questions was discussing how to disable them. You don't need to do anything to *enable* them, AFAIK...

Comment: The "Exit" action is really absent in FF 47.0. When I sent a screenshot, Gregorio Litenstein, the developer of `Keybinder`, pointed me out to [this add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mac-shortcuts/?src=search). Only after installing it, the "Exit" action appears in the "Other" category of `Keybinder`.

Answer (score 2):

I use Xubuntu, but plain Ubuntu probably has a similar function. Because Firefox itself does not allow to change the Ctrl-Q shortcut, I decided to steal that key combination away from Firefox.

The system gets keystrokes before applications do, so I used the Settings/Keyboard/Application shortcuts to define Ctrl-Q to start some non obtrusive application. I chose the Whisker application menu, but pick whatever. And look: even when Firefox has focus, Ctrl-Q does not reach it.

Comment: This blocks ctl-Q, but doesn't provide an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux with Firefox Quantum, there is currently a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1325692) that prevents extensions and explicit configuration from changing a builtin shortcut such as ctrl-Q. A workaround is to block it at the system level by e.g. installing the script from https://github.com/sasawat/firefox-ctrl-q-workaround and assigning it as the action of ctrl-Q as a global shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

In the electrolysis era I have come to rely on [menu wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard) to modify existing firefox hotkeys. It is a bit overkill since it also changes menu items, but seems to work well and is compatible.