# Firefox: how to change exit shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+Q) for 57+?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Ctrl+Shift+Q for other purpose,

[image]

so when I use it, the Firefox would close all things which is very annoying for me.

I tried to change the short cuts, but

- Firefox suggests Saka Key at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_windows-tabs, but I didn't see any configuration for exit (as below).

[image]

- From [How to change Mozilla Firefox quit shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/943200/how-to-change-mozilla-firefox-quit-shortcut), there is no current solution for Firefox 57+

Is it still possible for me to change the quit shortcut? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the firefox extension called 'Customizable Shortcuts from Mozilla'?

Comment: Is that extension present?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to edit the installed `browser/omni.ja` file (~10 minutes of work) or compile your own (~2-3 hours), then it's possible.

There are XUL files, where all these bindings are defined and it's relatively easy to change them, once you get a hang of it.

For a detailed description of both options (editing the downloaded binary or compiling your own), you can consult a very detailed description that I wrote recently when I wanted to do the same: https://github.com/nilcons/firefox-hacks

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Without actually providing the steps one must take, there is no answer in this post. Please [edit] your post to include this information, including the essential content of linked material.